# Node JS is async Read/Write safe?

Tags: node.js, express

Probably a dumb question, but if the program is asynchronously writing to a file, and you access that file while it's still writing, are the contents messed up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, it does not matter whether you are synchronously or asynchronously accessing a file: if some other process (yours or someone else) modifies the file while you are in the middle of reading, you will get inconsistent results.

The exact kind of inconsistency you'll see depends on how the file is written and when reading starts.

In node's default [mode](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback) (`w`), a file's existing contents are truncated when the file is opened.

- An in-flight read will stop early (without erroring), meaning you'll only have a percentage of the original file.
- A read started after the write begins will read up to the last written byte.  Depending on how far along and fast the write is, and how you read the file, the read may or may not see the complete file.

If the file is written in `r+` mode, the contents are not truncated when the file is opened for writing.  This means a read will see part of the old data and part of the new data.  Things are further muddied if the write changes the file size.

This is all true regardless of whether you use streams (ie `createReadStream`), `readFile`, or even `readFileSync`.  Any part of the file on disk can be changed while node is in the process of buffering the file into memory.  (The only notable exception here is if you use `writeFileSync` and then `readFileSync` *in the same process*, since the write call would prevent the read from starting until after the write is complete.  However, this still doesn't prevent other processes from changing the file mid-read, and you shouldn't be using the sync methods anyway.)

In other words, reading and writing a file is non-atomic.  To avoid inconsistency, you should write the file with a temporary name and then [`rename`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback) it when the write is complete.